# Rails carrierwave very slow upload with animated gif even with small file size

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I'm trying to upload an animated gif with just **611KB** file size and its taking about **30** to **40 seconds** or longer than that to finish. I've already adjusted my server configuration **client_max_body_size** to accept **10MB** file upload, and it's already working fine and not taking too long like the problem that i'm stating right now with jpg, jpeg and png files as per tested. I'm not sure if the cause of this is in the server configuration or the process of generating versions of the file by carrierwave that i have pasted in here. I did a lot of research already but it seems i can't find same problem as i have. By the way i am using a javascript uploader on this. Does any one here encountered the same problem with Rails carrierwave?

And also i have this message in my firebug:

```
... POST data request size limit has been reached by Firebug. ...
```

Here's the gems that i used and carrierwave code for my uploader:

```
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'carrierwave-aws'
gem 'carrierwave-base64'
```

app/uploaders/photo_uploader.rb

```
require 'securerandom'

class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  storage :aws

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  process :auto_orient
  def auto_orient
    manipulate! do |img|
      img.auto_orient!
      img = yield(img) if block_given?
      img
    end
  end

  version :scaled_512 do
    process :resize_to_fit => [512, 512]
  end

  version :thumb_425, from_version: :scaled_512 do
    process :resize_to_fill => [425, 212]
  end

  version :thumb_256, from_version: :scaled_512 do
    process :resize_to_fill => [256, 256]
  end

  def remove!
    begin
      super
    rescue Fog::Storage::Rackspace::NotFound
    end
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

  def filename
    "#{secure_token}.#{file.extension}" if original_filename.present?
  end

  protected
  def secure_token
    var = :"@#{mounted_as}_secure_token"
    model.instance_variable_get(var) or model.instance_variable_set(var, SecureRandom.uuid)
  end

end
```

Comment: Can't you just disable your processing and versions for test to see if that is your problem?

Comment: I've already tried commenting the code for the photo version processing and the result is **10.78s** for the uploader without version processing and **49.30s** with the processing. And this is in my localhost only, this is takes too long in the server.